# T-SQL query: How To insert average value from last 5 messages

Tags: t-sql, average, sql-insert

I have a database with messages from several devices. I'm building a machine learning algorithm and before that I need to calculate some average values from already sent messages.

I'm taking input from a cosmos DB and want to save it to a T-SQL table. I want to take the current message Temperature + the last 4 messages and calculate the average and put it to a separate column. I have seen lots of posts about this but I can't any of them to work.

This is the code when i try to add a test message:

```
INSERT INTO PredictionMessages 
(
    [Temperature], 
    [Humidity], 
    [Created],
    [DeviceId],
    [temperatureAlert],
    [averageTempLast5]
)
VALUES 
(
    22, 55, GETDATE(), 1, 'false', 
    (
       SELECT TOP (5) AVG([Temperature]) 
       FROM Messages WHERE DeviceId = 1 
       GROUP BY Created 
       ORDER BY [Created] DESC 
    )
)
GO
```

I have tried several different approaches with different problems but this is the best try yet. This one's give me ErrorMessage:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

What am I doing wrong or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update : Just fixed the SQL by adding the `x` alias to the inner subselect

You need to change your subquery so it only returns one value, right now it is returning 5 due to the `select top 5`

One approach could be to do something like

```
SELECT AVG(x.Temperature) from (
SELECT TOP (5) Temperature 
       FROM Messages WHERE DeviceId = 1 
       ORDER BY [Created] DESC 
) x
```

instead of

```
SELECT TOP (5) AVG([Temperature]) 
       FROM Messages WHERE DeviceId = 1 
       GROUP BY Created 
       ORDER BY [Created] DESC
```

So basically you are first selecting the top 5 rows based on the created column (giving the result the alias `x`), and then aggregating them to one row